# Android gallery fling with image view

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I have a android gallery and image view in my main layout. When I touch an image in Gallery I display that image in the imageview below. What I am trying to achieve is I want the user to be able to fling the image itself to left or right to go to next or previous image. I have been able to do that also. But at the same time when the user flings to next image I want the Gallery on top also to scroll to next image. How Can I achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29) method.

```
if( fling right ){
   gallery.setSelection(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1);
}
```